# Not able to create stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create stored procedure in mysql but showing following errors..

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Procedure as bellow..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getSchools( IN masterschools_id int )
BEGIN
 select * from masterschools where id =masterschools_id;
END
```

Comment: Try setting delimiter to $$ before the create - don't forget to set it back to whatever your current settings are after the end statement. If you have mysql workbench you can have it generate the right code for you...

Answer (score 0):

**Tried this and its working properly...**

```
 create DEFINER=products@localhost procedure getMyschools ()
  NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER
select * from masterschools;
```