# Unknown error in mariadb with stored procedure

Tags: mariadb

I'm creating a website for practice and I needed to make a SQL database to store users and their priviliges. I wanted to make a stored procedure for retrieving the privileges of the user selected, but for some reason it says I have a syntax error but I'm very confused as to what it is
This is all on phpmyadmin hosted on xampp, and unfortunately I'm very unacustomed with sql and have tried to search everywhere with the error

procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CHECKUSERPRIVILEGES(
    IN username VARCHAR(32),
    IN pass VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        userid INT(11); <-- error here
    SELECT
        UserID
    INTO userid
FROM
    users
WHERE
    Username = username AND Pass = pass; DECLARE priviligeid BIGINT(16);
SELECT
    PrivilegeID
INTO privilegeid
FROM
    userprivleges
WHERE
    UserID = userid;
SELECT
    *
FROM PRIVILEGES
WHERE
    PrivilegeID = privilegeid
GO;
```

error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
```

I have also tried to switch out the `INT(11)` for just `INT` or `INTEGER` but still the same error

I found a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997903/not-able-to-create-stored-procedure-in-mysql) but I don't understand what the answer is doing and how to apply it to my problem

Edit:
I have tried moving the `DECLARE`s to the start and still the same error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CHECKUSERPRIVILEGES(
    IN username VARCHAR(32),
    IN pass VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        userid INT(11);
    DECLARE
        priviligeid BIGINT(16);
    SELECT
        UserID
    INTO userid
FROM
    users
WHERE
    Username = username AND Pass = pass;
SELECT
    PrivilegeID
INTO privilegeid
FROM
    userprivleges
WHERE
    UserID = userid;
SELECT
    *
FROM PRIVILEGES
WHERE
    PrivilegeID = privilegeid
GO;
```

Comment: what is your MySQL version?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: when I try it on 11.2.2, it gets an error on your second DECLARE: DECLARE can only be used immediately after the BEGIN of a stored procedure.

Comment: 10.4.32-MariaDB

Comment: ahh, i shall try declaring it at the start, i did not know that

Comment: @ysth i have tried declaring at the start just after the `begin` but still the same error

Comment: fixing your inconsistent variable name spelling and replacing GO with ; END makes it work for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/Y2BuGU0a
are you sure you are getting the same error (same "near ...")?

Comment: Still does not like it, same error same location

Comment: @ysth do you think that it is an error with phpmyadmin rather than the mysql code? (I'm not used to phpmyadmin so I may have messed something up there)

Comment: did you copy/paste exactly what was in my fiddle?  I'd guess you have something different.  I don't use phpmyadmin, but I can't think of any other reason it would be giving that error still

Comment: maybe you need `delimiter $$` at the top and `$$` at the bottom

Comment: @ysth that completely fixed the problem, thank you very much, what is the point of the `delimiter $$` and `$$` just out of curiosity

Comment: tells phpadmin to submit everything up to the end $$ as a single statement; apparently it defaults to breaking it up on semicolons, so the server was only getting up to the first `;` and giving the error

Comment: `GO;` is a SQL Server ism, not for MariaDB. This query looks like it should be a `JOIN`. See other answers but don't do clear text password. For your procedure, where is the output, how are you going to use the procedure?

Comment: What is the end of the multi-statement `CREATE`?  The syntax can't use `;`.  So it has the `DELIMITER` kludge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote your stored procedure from scratch if you are interested, you can use this stored procedure or you can maybe think of error handling and use select count in your stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE CheckUserPrivileges(
IN pUserID INT,
IN pPass VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE privilegeCount INT;

-- Check if the user exists
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO privilegeCount
FROM users
WHERE UserID = pUserID AND Pass = pPass;

IF privilegeCount = 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'User not found or incorrect password';
ELSE
    -- Check user privileges
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO privilegeCount
    FROM userprivileges
    WHERE UserID = pUserID;

    IF privilegeCount > 0 THEN
        -- User has privileges, you can add more logic if needed
        SELECT p.PrivilegeID
        FROM userprivileges up
        JOIN privileges p ON up.PrivilegeID = p.PrivilegeID
        WHERE up.UserID = pUserID;
    ELSE
        -- User has no privileges
        SELECT 'User has no privileges';
    END IF;
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```